# Declaring Mongoose Schema in Angular Models

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular

I have a REST API based off Node.js, Express.js and Mongoose. I have an Angular5 application that consumes the API. I have a mongoose schema as below in the backend:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userid: { type: String, default: null },
  first_name: { type: String, required: true },
  last_name: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, trim: true, lowercase: true, unique: true, required: true },
  phone: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true },
  role: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Role' }],
  password: { type: String, required: true },
});
```

As you can see, I have role referenced from another schema. In the Angular part, I have defined the model as such:

```
export interface User {
    _id: String;
    userid: String;
    first_name: String;
    last_name: String;
    email: String;
    phone: Number;
    role: String[];
    password: String;
}
```

As you can see, I have defined the role as string array. I need this to be done so that in my Angular code, I can do create user functionality by just putting in the roleid in the role field of the user. But when I need to retrieve, I populate and return the data from API but the data is lost since I map the result to this interface. **How do I deal with this scenario? What is the best way to tackle and maintain uniformity in my application.**

Comment: There are couple of solutions: 1. Make another interface that has the populated role property; 2. Use TSOA on the backend

Comment: As for Roles, I think it’s better to be an enum rather than a whole schema itself.

Comment: @ChauTran as of now, I maintain 2 interfaces and work with but i dont think it is an ideal solution. Another thing you pointed out was enum - hoow exactly do you propose that? I dont understand how it can be made an enum. Any example would be great!

Comment: My bad for proposing `enum` without asking to clarify what information you have on your `Role`. I've been working with TypeScript on Node/Express backend lately so it's pretty easy regarding mapping these types. Maintaining 2 interfaces is not a bad idea though :) If you're willing to make a change to TS on the backend, I'm happy to help (TSOA package is awesome btw)